# how laravel url() method deremines host name in mail blade view

Tags: php, laravel, url, hostname

I can't figure out and docs lack info how laravel determines host name when sending email from balde view with link like this:

```php
<a target="_blank" href="{{url('/report')}}">Link to my website</a>
```

I thought it came from config/.env but is does not.
Docs only say about current request but with email there is no request to get the host name from.

Comment: I believe that setting is in `config/app.php`, via `'url' => env('APP_URL', 'https://localhost'),`. So it does draw from `.env`, using `APP_URL=http://localhost:8000` (or whatever yours is set to)

Comment: one think keep in mind if you are sending email using command line it treat as localhost.so better to mention url

Comment: @TimLewis.yes i was wrong .you are right

Comment: @JohnLobo No worries! Good note about CLI generation, but that is also handled by that setting :)

Comment: Is is really coming from .env? Changing APP_URL in .env from localhost to 127.0.0.1 didn’t change link path. It still shows http://localhost:8000.